# make CLOB backup column

Tags: oracle, clob

i got a 3 CLOB columns , i have to manipulate them and to recreate data i tryed to make backup columns, like this:

```
update
tbl_order_webform
set mail_bak = mail_html
```

but the back up column is empty after the script.

is this even possible? or is this any other way to create a back for them?

Comment: Did you commit after the update?

Comment: woops, ty... even thught i read something about this isnt possible, well thats for that. Thx again.

Comment: @Rene you may want to submit this as an answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your changes in order to see them in another session.